# Is it possible to run two unity simulations at the same time on same computer?

Tags: unity, simulations

I know it is possible to open multiple unity projects at the same time on the same computer but is it also possible to run two unity projects at the same time and on the same computer. I tried running two unity simulations simultaneously, the one I run lastly, ran fine but the one which I ran first slowed down.

Comment: What kind of "simulation" do you need to run? It might be easier for you to balance the workload & performance between the two by running them within one Unity instance, or running them headless so they're not fighting over the GPU...

Comment: It's a traffic scene. In a single unity project I've got multiple scenes already. For my problem, I need to run two separate unity projects simultaneously on the same computer

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple unity projects simultaneously on the same computer in the headless mode?

Comment: And what do you mean by "slowed down"? Did it visually seems to lag? I'm not familiar with Unity, but most likely is that it detects it's not the active application and so purposely reduces the frame rate (I would assume it does not affect the simulation frame rate, only the graphics frame rate). Check what happens when you change the active application and if the "slow down" changes as well.

Comment: Yes, it visually seems to lag. It detects that it is not the active application, so slows down, while the active application runs at the usual pace. When I change the active application, the current active one slows down and the other one speeds up. It does affect the simulation frame rate. I ran two same unity projects simultaneously on the same machine, the active project finished the simulation first while the non-active took long to finish.

Comment: Do you use the `Update` method, or the `FixedUpdated` method?

Comment: How have you configured your [Run in Background settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html) (either in the editor or [via code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html))?

Comment: @Alexandre Viallancourt , I used FixedUpdate.

Comment: @DMGregory I did not configure any Run in Background Settings.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to show your simulation to someone? In this case you can compile both projects, or you can add the two scenes with the simulations together.

Comment: @TomTsagk even if I add both the scenes, can I run both of them simultaneously?

Comment: @D.g You can do `LoadScene(sceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Additive);` this will add the new scene, and keep your old one as well, they will run at the same time. You can also merge them together.